# How to fix "While Loop in python " is not working in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

I'm a newbie in python and trying to learn some basics, I try to develop a small HANGMAN game. I stuck in while loop format, it shows nothing in results except ZERO index element in HANGMAN list.

```py
import random
HANGMAN = (
"""
-----
|    |
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
-------
"""
  ,
"""
-----
|   |
|   0
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
------
"""
  ,
"""
-----
|   |
|   0 
|   |
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
------
"""
  ,
"""
-----
|   |
|   0 
|  /|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
------
"""
  ,
"""
-----
|   |
|   0 
|  /|\
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
------
"""
  ,
"""
-----
|   |
|   0 
|  /|\
|  /
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
------
"""
  ,
"""
-----
|   |
|   0 
|  /|\
|  / \
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
------
""")
print(HANGMAN[0])

play_again = True

while play_again:

         words_list = ['abruptly', 'absurd', 'abyss', 'affix', 'askew', 'avenue', 'awkward', 'axiom', 'azure', 'bagpipes'
                                                                                                              'banjo',
                      'beekeeper',
                      'bikini',
                      'blitz',
                      'blizzard',
                      'boggle',
                      'bookworm',
                      'boxcar',
                      'boxful',
                      'buckaroo',
                      'buffalo',
                      'buffoon',
                      'buxom',
                      'buzzard',
                      'buzzing',
                      'buzzwords',
                      'caliph',
                      'cobweb',
                      'cockiness',
                      'croquet',
                      'crypt',
                      'curacao',
                      'cycle',
                      'daiquiri',
                      'dirndl',
                      'disavow',
                      'dizzying',
                      'duplex',
                      'dearies',
                      'embezzle',
                      'equip',
                      'espionage',
                      'edouard',
                      'exodus',
                      'faking',
                      'glyph',
                      'gnarly',
                      'fixable',
                      'fjord',
                      'flapjack',
                      'flopping',
                      'foxglove',
                      'frazzled',
                      'frizzled',
                      'fuchsia',
                      'funny',
                      'gabby',
                      'galaxy',
                      'galvanize',
                      'gazebo',
                      'gaiter',
                      'gimme',
                      'glowworm',
                      'gossip',
                      'grogginess',
                      'haiku',
                      'haphazard',
                      "stronghold",
                      "stymied",
                      "subway",
                      "swivel",
                      "syndrome",
                      "thriftless",
                      "thumbscrew",
                      "topaz",
                      "transcript",
                      "transgress",
                      "transplant",
                      "triathlon",
                      "twelfth",
                      "twelfths",
                      "unknown",
                      "unworthy",
                      "unzip",
                      "uptown",
                      "vaporize",
                      "vixen",
                      "vodka",
                      "voodoo",
                      "vortex",
                      "voyeurism",
                      "walkway",
                      "waltz",
                      "wave",
                      "wavy",
                      "waxy",
                      "wellspring",
                      "wheezy",
                      "whiskey",
                      "whizzing",
                      "whomever",
                      "wimpy",
                      "witchcraft",
                      "wizard",
                      "woozy",
                      "wristwatch",
                      "wavers",
                      "xylophone",
                      "yachtsman",
                      "yippee",
                      "yoked",
                      "youthful",
                      "yummy",
                      "zephyr",
                      "zigzag",
                      "zigzagging",
                      "zilch",
                      "zipper",
                      "zodiac",
                      "zombie"]
         chossenword = random.choice(words_list).lower()
         guess = None   #player guess input
         guessed_letters = []   #we add all of the users guesses to this list.
         blank_word = []  #repalcing all the letetrs of the chosen word with dashed symbol.
for letter in chossenword:
    blank_word.append('-')
attempt = 6

while attempt > 0:

        if (attempt!= 0 and "-" in blank_word):

            print(('\n You Have () attempts remaining.').format(attempt))

        try:
            guess == str(input('\n please select a letter between A_Z')).lower()
        except :
            print("that's not a valid input , please try again.")
            continue

        else:
            if not guess.isaplha():
                print('that is not a letter, please try again ')
                continue

            elif len(guess) > 1:
             print("that's is more tahn one letetre , please try again")
             continue

            elif guess in guessed_letters:
                print(" you have already guessed that letter , please try again.")
                continue
            else:
                pass

            guessed_letters.append(guess)

            if guess not in chossenword:
                attempts=-1
                print(HANGMAN[(len(HANGMAN)-1)-attempts])

            else :
                SearchMore = True
                startsearchindex == 0
                while searchMore:
                    try :
                        foundAtIndex = chossenword.index(guess, startsearchindex)
                        blank_word[foundAtIndex]= guess
                        startsearchindex = foundAtIndex + 1
                    except :
                        searchMore = False

            print("".join(blank_word))

            if attempts == 0:
                print("sorry. the game is over , The word was" + chossenword)
                print("\nWould you like to play again ?")
                response =input('>').lower()
                if response not in ("yes","y"):
                    play_again = False
                    print("thanks for playing HANGMAN!")
                break

            if "-" not in blank_word :
                print(("\n Congratualtion! {} was the word").format(chossenword))
                print("\n World you like to play again ?")
                response = input('>').lower()
                if response not in ("yes","y"):
                 play_again = False
                 print("thanks for playing HANGMAN!")
                break
```

Nothing work in while loop.

Comment: **Minimal**, working example would help. For example we don't need to see hangman's animation nor we need all words, as probably two would do fine. Both eliminations would make understanding code much easier.

Answer (score 2):

I got your code working on my machine with a bit of syntax and whitespace finessing. Overall, you were on the right track! The reason the `while` loop was only returning the first element of the `HANGMAN` loop was because the code wasn't actually decrementing the `attempt` value. You were doing

`attempt=-1`

instead of

`attempt -= 1`

and that was setting `attempt` to `-1` each iteration. Using the `-=` operator will actually decrement it.

There were also variable declarations with incorrect syntax (you assign variables in Python with `=`, not `==`), and some inconsistent variable usages (`attempts` instead of `attempt`, `searchmore` and `searchMore`, etc.).

Finally, I moved the word list outside of the while loop. You don't need to re-create that list every time the while loop runs.

```
import random

HANGMAN = ("""| | | | | | | | | | | |""" ,
           """| | | 0 | | | | | | | |""" ,
           """| | | 0 | | | | | | | | |
                    |""" ,
           """| | | 0 |
                   /| | | | | | | | |""" ,
           """| | | 0 |
                   /|\ | | | | | | | |""" ,
           """| | | 0 |
                   /|\ |
                   / | | | | | | |""" ,
           """| | | 0 |
                   /|\ |
                   / \ | | | | | | |"""
          )

words_list = ['abruptly',
                   'absurd',
                   'abyss',
                   'affix',
                   'askew',
                   'avenue',
                   'awkward',
                   'axiom',
                   'azure',
                   'bagpipes',
                   'banjo',
                   'beekeeper',
                   'bikini',
                   'blitz',
                   'blizzard',
                   'boggle',
                   'bookworm',
                   'boxcar',
                   'boxful',
                   'buckaroo',
                   'buffalo',
                   'buffoon',
                   'buxom',
                   'buzzard',
                   'buzzing',
                   'buzzwords',
                   'caliph',
                   'cobweb',
                   'cockiness',
                   'croquet',
                   'crypt',
                   'curacao',
                   'cycle',
                   'daiquiri',
                   'dirndl',
                   'disavow',
                   'dizzying',
                   'duplex',
                   'dearies',
                   'embezzle',
                   'equip',
                   'espionage',
                   'edouard',
                   'exodus',
                   'faking',
                   'glyph',
                   'gnarly',
                   'fixable',
                   'fjord',
                   'flapjack',
                   'flopping',
                   'foxglove',
                   'frazzled',
                   'frizzled',
                   'fuchsia',
                   'funny',
                   'gabby',
                   'galaxy',
                   'galvanize',
                   'gazebo',
                   'gaiter',
                   'gimme',
                   'glowworm',
                   'gossip',
                   'grogginess',
                   'haiku',
                   'haphazard',
                   "stronghold",
                   "stymied",
                   "subway",
                   "swivel",
                   "syndrome",
                   "thriftless",
                   "thumbscrew",
                   "topaz",
                   "transcript",
                   "transgress",
                   "transplant",
                   "triathlon",
                   "twelfth",
                   "twelfths",
                   "unknown",
                   "unworthy",
                   "unzip",
                   "uptown",
                   "vaporize",
                   "vixen",
                   "vodka",
                   "voodoo",
                   "vortex",
                   "voyeurism",
                   "walkway",
                   "waltz",
                   "wave",
                   "wavy",
                   "waxy",
                   "wellspring",
                   "wheezy",
                   "whiskey",
                   "whizzing",
                   "whomever",
                   "wimpy",
                   "witchcraft",
                   "wizard",
                   "woozy",
                   "wristwatch",
                   "wavers",
                   "xylophone",
                   "yachtsman",
                   "yippee",
                   "yoked",
                   "youthful",
                   "yummy",
                   "zephyr",
                   "zigzag",
                   "zigzagging",
                   "zilch",
                   "zipper",
                   "zodiac",
                   "zombie"]

print(HANGMAN[0])
play_again = True

while play_again:

    chosen_word = random.choice(words_list)

    guess = None   #player guess input

    guessed_letters = []   #we add all of the user's guesses to this list.

    blank_word = []  # replacing all the letters of the chosen word with dashed symbol
    for letter in chosen_word: # creating list with dashes instead of letters for the word
        blank_word.append('-')

    attempt = 6 # the number of incorrect attempts a user gets

    while attempt > 0: # while the user still has valid guesses left

        if (attempt!= 0 and "-" in blank_word): # while player can still guess

            print(('\n You Have {} attempts remaining.').format(attempt)) # tell the user how many attempts are left

            try:
                guess = str(input('\n please select a letter between A-Z')).lower() # enter a letter, lowercase it
            except: # will never hit this
                print("that's not a valid input , please try again.")
                continue

            if not guess.isalpha(): # check if the letter is alphabetical
                print('that is not a letter, please try again ')
                continue

            elif len(guess) > 1:
                print("that's is more than one letter , please try again")
                continue

            elif guess in guessed_letters:
                print(" you have already guessed that letter , please try again.")
                continue

            guessed_letters.append(guess) # add guess to guessed_letters

            print("Guessed letters: ",  guessed_letters)

            if guess not in chosen_word: # if the guessed letter isn't in the chosen_word
                attempt -= 1 # reduce # of attempts available
                print(HANGMAN[(len(HANGMAN)-1)-attempt]) # print the element of HANGMAN at (length of HANGMAN - 1) - the # of attempts

            else: # if the guessed letter IS in the chosen_word
                searchMore = True
                startsearchindex = 0
                while searchMore:
                    try :
                        foundAtIndex = chosen_word.index(guess, startsearchindex)
                        blank_word[foundAtIndex]= guess
                        startsearchindex = foundAtIndex + 1
                    except :
                        searchMore = False

            print("".join(blank_word))

        if attempt == 0: # no more attempts
            print("sorry. the game is over , The word was" + chosen_word)
            print("\nWould you like to play again?")
            response =input('>').lower()
            if response not in ("yes","y"):
                play_again = False
                print("thanks for playing HANGMAN!")
                break

        if "-" not in blank_word :
            print(("\n Congratualtion! {} was the word").format(chosen_word))
            print("\n World you like to play again ?")
            response = input('>').lower()
            if response not in ("yes","y"):
                play_again = False
                print("thanks for playing HANGMAN!")
                break
```

Hope this helps!